# [Eclipse] /.../fuerte_workspace/.../talker: error while loading shared libraries: libxmlrpcpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I just run a simple talker.cpp in eclipse. When I run using binary file, the terminal shows

```
/home/quocmd/fuerte_workspace/sanbox/beginner_tutorials/bin/talker: error while loading shared libraries: libxmlrpcpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried in ubuntu terminal, it can run well. How could I resolve it. My eclipse is Photon version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303689/%5Beclipse%5D-/home/quocmd/fuerte_workspace/sanbox/beginner_tutorials/bin/talker:-error-while-loading-shared-libraries:-libxmlrpcpp.so:-cannot-open-shared-object-file:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2018-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-18**:
You tagged this question with `melodic`, but your path shows `fuerte_workspace`. That doesn't match.

Can you please clarify which of the two ROS versions you are using, and why there is a `fuerte_workspace` there?

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2018-09-19**:
Hi it is just the name of my folder, but I use melodic version, guy! And I already figured out the solution, add LD_PATH_LIB=opt/ros/melodic/lib in Environment of Run as Configuration. :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-19**:
If you can post that as an answer, then you can accept your own answer and that will clearly show future visitors that your issue was resolved.

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2018-09-19**:
I did it :D

**Comment by [manuaatitya](https://answers.ros.org/users/53247/manuaatitya/) on 2020-04-27**:
Hi,
I'm facing a similar issue even after adding LD_PATH_LIB to my environment variables in my catkin_workspace.
Pls help me with the same.
I'm using ros melodic on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

error while loading shared libraries: libxmlrpcpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

echo $LD_PATH_LIB

/opt/ros/melodic/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already figured out the solution, add LD_PATH_LIB=opt/ros/melodic/lib in Environment of Run as Configuration. :)

---

Originally posted by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) with karma: 89 on 2018-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manuaatitya](https://answers.ros.org/users/53247/manuaatitya/) on 2020-04-27**:
Hi, I'm facing a similar issue even after adding LD_PATH_LIB to my environment variables in my catkin_workspace. Pls help me with the same.

I'm using ros melodic on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

error while loading shared libraries: libxmlrpcpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

echo $LD_PATH_LIB

/opt/ros/melodic/lib

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those still having issues, try:

`sudo apt install libxmlrpcpp-dev`

---

Originally posted by [Ãustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/78793/%C3%A3ustin/) with karma: 11 on 2021-07-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1